# Guidance on how to make micro-services communicate effectively

Tags: rest, design-patterns, microservices, api-design

We are embarking on a new project development , where we will have multiple micro-services communicating each other to provide information in cloud native system. Our application will be decomposed into multiple services like Text Cleaner , Entities Extractor, Entities Resolver , Output Converter. As you can see in diagram we have some forking where input to one service in required by other service and so forth.

Only one service is going to be exposed outside. Others would be internal. And we have to provide synchronous response to clients.

I wanted to check if some one can guide me here to best patterns:

1- Should we have one Wrapper class which has model classes for all projects as one all of details is needed in final output convertors or how should the data flow so data is sorted out in last micro-service. We want to keep systems loosely coupled and are thinking about how orchestrate this flow without having a middle layer which composes all this data?

2- How to orchestrate this flow? Service Mesh / Api Gateway?

[image: Service Dataflow patterns]

Comment: are all these services exposed to outside world as independent micro-services ? Or only Test Cleaner is exposed ? Also, how is the output expected .. is it a synchronous or asynchronous response ?

Comment: Only one of the service is going to be exposed outside. Others would be internal. We are providing synchronous response to clients

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a workflow based solution.. When so many steps are involved ; the only response you can give to consumer is that request accepted.. and in background the process starts..You cannot let consumer wait for very long because they will get connection time out.

if all these services are deployed on different servers ( which should be the case for Micro services definition for scalability); you can communicate via HTTP or using some messaging solution like JMS or if u are deployed on cloud ; they give workflow based services..

Comment: We will be on cloud based service on ecs cluster. The timings are very strict but we will see and make do.. Thanks

Comment: if u are sure that you want to reply back to consumer synchronously and once complete process is complete; then HTTP is the ONLY solution to communicate between different services.. because we use JMS to make things asynchronous.